# Validating arguments of private methods because of Reflection in C#

Tags: c#, validation, reflection

I am wondering whether it is necessary to validate once more the arguments passed to private methods of classes which without using Reflection would only be called by public methods in the same class.

If the private method instantiates an object that needs to be disposed (before something goes wrong because of bad arguments), an exception could be thrown (in which case the object would be disposed anyway), right?

I was viewing some of the source code of .NET (mainly the `String` and `Stream` classes). I found that some private methods arguments are verified with contracts, but in others no occur check.

Code that does not validate once more the arguments (taken from the `String` class). In this case a `NullReferenceException` can be thrown because of the `trimChars` argument.

```
    [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
    private String TrimHelper(char[] trimChars, int trimType) {
        //end will point to the first non-trimmed character on the right
        //start will point to the first non-trimmed character on the Left
        int end = this.Length-1;
        int start=0;

        //Trim specified characters.
        if (trimType !=TrimTail)  {
            for (start=0; start < this.Length; start++) {
                int i = 0;
                char ch = this[start];
                for( i = 0; i < trimChars.Length; i++) {
        // ... more code
```

A code that validates the arguments twice (once in public and once in private method) is this (taken from `Stream` class).

```
   [HostProtection(ExternalThreading = true)]
   [ComVisible(false)]
   public virtual Task CopyToAsync(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
      if (destination == null)
         throw new ArgumentNullException("destination");
         // ... more code goes here
      return CopyToAsyncInternal(destination, bufferSize, cancellationToken);
   } 


    private async Task CopyToAsyncInternal(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Contract.Requires(destination != null);
        // ... more code
    }
```

Which is the best practice, or does it depend on the situation - whether it is a class library that is only used in a specific project or it would be used in different contexts that can't be known in advance?

Answer (score 2):

> I am wondering whether it is necessary to validate once more the arguments passed to private methods of classes which without using Reflection would only be called by public methods in the same class.

That mainly depends on whether you support third-party callers using reflection to call those methods. Most people don't, and don't design their code to support it. I also don't, and don't recommend it.

Would you worry about breaking third-party callers using reflection when you rename a `private` method? If not, then don't worry about the code in those methods either.

But see below.

> If the private method instantiates an object that needs to be disposed (before something goes wrong because of bad arguments), an exception could be thrown (in which case the object would be disposed anyway), right?

No. `Dispose()` is a method that many classes implement, usually along with the `IDisposable` interface, but for the runtime, neither this interface nor the method has any specific meaning.

If an object is instantiated, and there are no references to that object, it will (at some point) be garbage-collected, at which point the class's destructor (aka finalizer) runs. There's no rule that says the `Dispose()` method and the destructor must do the same thing, and there are sometimes good reasons why they don't do the same thing. But if you have any unmanaged resources, then almost certainly, both will release those resources.

> Which is the best practice, or does it depend on the situation - whether it is a class library that is only used in a specific project or it would be used in different contexts that can't be known in advance?

Well, one reason it *can* make sense to do contract validation in `private` methods, is if you move the contract validation *out* of the `public` methods.

Given

```
public void Foo(string x) { Baz(x, false); }
public void Bar(string x) { Baz(x, true); }
private void Baz(string x, bool y) {
  if (x == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("x");
  // ...
}
```

it may make sense to put the contract validation in `Baz`, to reduce code duplication.

Another time it may make sense to put contract validation in `private` methods is if you have external tools that do static contract checking (that'll mainly be Code Contracts), and the contract checker is otherwise unable to verify that your method's body doesn't violate any other method's contract:

```
private void Foo(string x) { Bar(x); }
```

If the contract checker sees that `Bar` requires `x` to be non-null, and is unable to verify that all calls to `Foo` will pass a non-null value, it may produce a warning inside `Foo`. (Or it may produce a warning inside `Foo`'s caller. It depends.)

Of course, if Code Contracts is used, then the earlier removal of code duplication is a bad idea: Code Contracts does need the contracts to be present in the public methods.

Comment: About the Dispose thing, I meant objects that hold unmanaged resources (in which case I guess I'm right about this :) ). So from your answer I can assume that if my private methods are not supposed to be called with reflection (you said about third parties), I can safely ignore the validation of the arguments in these. Of course you're right about code duplication where it is really a good idea to move it inside them.

Comment: @RosenDimov It still won't be the `Dispose()` method that gets called, it'll still be the destructor. :) But beware: that destructor does *not* necessarily get called as soon as you might want, just at some later time when the garbage collector happens to run. If you have any object holding unmanaged resources, you should make sure to call the `Dispose()` method in the event of an exception (typically by wrapping it in a `using` statement). If that unmanaged resource is a file, for example, the file may remain locked longer than you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer to your question, but it's too long for a comment:

`Contract.Requires` is not the same as validating a parameter and throwing an exception if the validation fails.

Unless you configure Code Contracts to use run-time checks the `Contract.Requires` won't even make it into the final assembly code (same `Stream` example decompiled using dotPeek)

```
private Task CopyToAsyncInternal(Stream destination, int bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Stream.<CopyToAsyncInternal>d__2 stateMachine;
    stateMachine.<>__this = this;
    stateMachine.destination = destination;
```

There is no validation in there and the `Stream.<CopyToAsyncInternal>d__2` does not validate its `destination` field in any way before accessing it in its `MoveNext` method.

But using `Contract.Requires` in private methods allows for a better static analysis of contracts.

Comment: *Any* `async` method's body, including `CopyToAsyncInternal`, is re-written to use a compiler-generated state machine class, where that class contains the actual code, and the method merely sets things up so that the class can get used. You'd need to inspect that class's methods' IL to check whether `Contract.Requires` got removed.

Comment: That does seem more convincing. :)